# Не переведена часть текста на странице удаления учётной записи заблокированного участника

Tags: дефект, локализация, профиль-участника, блокировка

На странице удаления учетной записи не переведены три-четыре абзаца. Они показываются только тем, у кого учётная запись заблокирована, т.е. скриншот предъявить не могу.

Ссылка: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/delete/current

Comment: Совершенно не понятно что же не переведено. Ссылка даёт 404. Картинки нет. Что делать-то? Могу только предложить закрыть пока.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ в ссылку нужно подставить свой номер, там указано. Т.е. для вас будет такая ссылка: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/delete/176217 Я не умею давать индивидуальную ссылку для каждого пользователя. Ну и по ссылке вы все равно ничего не увидите, потому что**показываются только тем, у кого учетная запись заблокирована*. Можете написать комментарий с "проявлениями невежливости", если повезет, то заблокируют ("с целью дать остыть" хахаха). Тогда увидите.

Comment: А кого блокировали-то? Скрин вовремя не сделан? Что за текст там хоть?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ меня блокировали, скрин не делал, потому что зачем, когда заблокирован написать ничего нельзя. А сейчас там текст короче и того фрагмента в середине нет

Comment: Слова хоть какие-то запомнились? Можно поискать по traducir тогда из списка непереведённых. По `suspend` + `delete` что-то подходящего не обнаружилось.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Не. Был абзац текста, потом ненумерованный список из 2-3 пунктов и еще абзац.

Comment: Это скорее всего вообще разные строки. Либо вспоминать надо, либо в баню идти, либо к девелоперам за помощью.

Comment: [Попробуем добыть](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386574/339911)

Comment: да, точно, там о том, что если удалить и восстановить профиль, то блокировка продолжится на оставшийся срок.

Comment: Можешь попробовать их [тут](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?translationStatus=2) найти?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ что-то не находится вот так сходу, уже разные слова поискал